putting trim statement in LINQ
I have the employee numbers in the database starting stored this way
EmployeeNumber
E123456
E999999
E666666
E111111
444444

Some value starts with "E" and some don't
I want to write a LINQ statement to match the database EmployeeNumber with employeeId that is passed from web. I tried writing LINQ statement like this:
_akContext.EmployeeInfos.Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber.TrimStart('E') == employeeId).OrderBy(e => e.EmployeeInfoId).Select(e => e.EmployeeInfoId).ToList();

With the above LINQ statement, I keep getting an error saying:
.Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber.TrimStart(E) == __TrimStart_0)' could not be translated

below is the screenshot:
The only way, I can think of is loop through the database and remove all "E" and then compare EmployeeNumber with employeeId, but that will be two step process. I was wondering if there is any way to trim E in the same LINQ query and then return the result. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

What database are you using?

I am using Microsoft SQL

What is the type of employeeId?

the type of employeeId is string

Try using TrimStart overload accepting array of characters (based on the source code it seems to be translatable):
_akContext.EmployeeInfos
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber.TrimStart(new []{'E'}) == employeeId)

Though this overload is not listed in the Function Mappings of the Microsoft SQL Server Provider.
If that does not work you can try to work around with replace:
_akContext.EmployeeInfos
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber.Replace("E", "") == employeeId)

Other options would include creating a computed column in the database which will hold trimmed value or formatting data client side (which arguably should be the go to option in this particular case):
_akContext.EmployeeInfos
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber == employeeId 
         || e.EmployeeNumber == ("E" + employeeId))

P.S.
I would highly recommend to normalize data (i.e. remove E's from the EmployeeNumber) in the database if possible or maybe it can be worth looking into creating appropriate index on the trimmed version of the EmployeeNumber (depends on usage patterns and data size).

It seems to me like you're approaching this from the wrong end. Even if it worked, would it make sense to trim every value in the database? Surely it's much simpler to work out how the employee would be formatted in the database, and then do a direct comparison with that, taking advantage of database indexes etc:
// Add any extra logic here such as padding.
var prefixedEmployeeId = $"E{employeeId}";
// Again, potentially apply zero-padding. The use
// of a separate variable name makes the purpose clearer.
var unprefixedEmployeeId = employeeId */;

var employees = _akContext.EmployeeInfos
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber == prefixedEmployeeId ||
                e.EmployeeNumber == unprefixedEmployeeId)
    .OrderBy(e => e.EmployeeInfoId)
    .Select(e => e.EmployeeInfoId)
    .ToList();

That could be a problem if your employee IDs are formatted really inconsistently in the database, (e.g. some using E, some using EE, some not using E at all) but I would really hope that's not the case. If it's just a case of "some E-prefixed" and "some not-E-prefixed" then presenting both in the query should be fine - and I'd still argue that's better than trimming. Fixing the database to be consistent would definitely be better though...

the issue is in the database some value starts with E and some dont.

How about:  .Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber == formattedEmployeeId || e.EmployeeNumber == employeeId) ?

I suspect that employee "number" is like a telephone "number"—i.e., it is a string that is usually made of digits, where leading zeros are still significant. So maybe giving it a numeric type in the database isn't such a good suggestion?

@Anjali: Firstly, that seems like information that should have been in the question to start with. Secondly, WillC's idea should still work. I believe this should still be a more effective option than the trimming as per the first approach in Guru Stron's answer.

@AndrewMorton: It depends what's meant by "leading zeros are still significant". If "E0003" and "E03" are used as different identifiers, then yes, that would prevent the use of a numeric type... but I'd suggest that's already a huge problem in the design.

I think we're all in agreement that the design needs to be improved :)

The most performant and simple approach (already mentioned by @guru-stron - but worth highlighting)
var employeeId2 = "E" + employeeId;

_akContext.EmployeeInfos
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber == employeeId 
             || e.EmployeeNumber == employeeId2)


Compute prefixed variant locally once
Leverage EmployeeNumber index
No overhead for computed column and/or additional index in the DB

